# Add subsection suffix values to pandas column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say that I have a dataframe with multiple columns. One column establish an identification number (ID) for some guys and other column establish some feature of them, let's say the degree of misdeeds that have committed. An example of that:

```
`df
Out[63]: 
    Crime  ID
0      13   1
1      13   1
2      12   1
3      12   1
4      13   3
5      13   3
6      13   3
7      63   3
8      63   3
9      63   3
10     63   3
11      3   3
12      7   6
13      7   6
14     13   6
15     13   6
16     45   6`
```

Is possible to categorize the IDs by the diversity of crimes? A possible output would be:

```
`df1
Out[64]: 
    Crime  ID
0      13   1
1      13   1
2      12   1.1
3      12   1.1
4      13   3
5      13   3
6      13   3
7      63   3.1
8      63   3.1
9      63   3.1
10     63   3.1
11      3   3.2
12      7   6
13      7   6
14     13   6.1
15     13   6.1
16     45   6.2`
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a good way to do this in a vectorized way, but it's relatively easy to do by looping.

First, you need a dict mapping (Crime, ID) pairs to IDs, so that, e.g., you can give row 9 the same ID as row 7.

Next, you need a dict mapping IDs to the highest sub-IDs used so far, so that, e.g., you can give row 16 a different ID than rows 12 and 14.

Something like this (untested):

```
def remap(df):
    pairmap = {}
    subidmap = {}
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if (row.Crime, row.ID) not in pairmap:
            if row.ID not in subidmap:
                subidmap[row.ID] = 0
                subid = str(row.ID)
            else:
                subidmap[row.ID] += 1
                subid = f'{row.ID}.{subidmap[row.ID]}'
            pairmap[row.Crime, row.ID] = subid
        yield pairmap[row.Crime, row.ID]    

df1.ID = list(remap(df1))
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better solution, but right now I'm thinking a nested `groupby` can do this.

```
v = df.groupby('ID', sort=False).apply(
        lambda x: x.groupby('Crime', sort=False).ngroup()).reset_index(drop=True)
df['ID'] = np.where(
        v.eq(0), df['ID'], df['ID'].astype(str) + '.' + v.astype(str))
```

```
df
    Crime   ID
0      13    1
1      13    1
2      12  1.1
3      12  1.1
4      13    3
5      13    3
6      13    3
7      63  3.1
8      63  3.1
9      63  3.1
10     63  3.1
11      3  3.2
12      7    6
13      7    6
14     13  6.1
15     13  6.1
16     45  6.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby` with `factorize`

```
s=df.groupby(['ID'],as_index=False)['Crime'].apply(lambda x : ('.'+pd.Series(pd.factorize(x)[0]).astype(str)).replace('.0','')).reset_index(drop=True)
s
Out[121]: 
0       
1       
2     .1
3     .1
4       
5       
6       
7     .1
8     .1
9     .1
10    .1
11    .2
12      
13      
14    .1
15    .1
16    .2
Name: Crime, dtype: object

df.ID.astype(str)+s
Out[122]: 
0       1
1       1
2     1.1
3     1.1
4       3
5       3
6       3
7     3.1
8     3.1
9     3.1
10    3.1
11    3.2
12      6
13      6
14    6.1
15    6.1
16    6.2
dtype: object
```